# What is the correct way to construct a URL from the content of a JSON element to avoid encoded characters in output?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, twitter

I am trying to send the output of a JSON message to Twitter like so:

```js
         $.getJSON(
          'http://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=1&callback=',
          'json',
          function(data) {
            $("#quote-content").html(data[0].content + "<br> --" + data[0].title);
            tweetText = data[0].content.replace(/<\/?[^>]+>/gi, '');
            url = "https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=" + '"' + tweetText + '"';
            console.log(url);
            $('#tweet').attr("href", url);
        }
    );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The issue is, when there is a character present in the data such as a single quote (apostrophe), dash, or double quote, the content cuts off like this:

Original String:

> Almost everything – all external expectations, all pride, all fear of
>   embarrassment or failure – these things just fall away in the face of
>   death, leaving only what is truly important.

Tweet cuts off at first unhandled character:

> "Almost everything

[Screenshot Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jqMbV.png)

========================================================================

In order to correct that issue, I tried changing:

`url = "https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=" + '"' + tweetText + '"';`

to

`url = "https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=" + '"' + encodeURIComponent(tweetText) + '"';`

Now the output is like this:

Original String:

> Best thing about creating something is that it starts living it’s own
>   life.

Tweet text is now fully displaying, but showing encoded characters:

[Screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/afWu0.png)

Sorry, I had to post a screenshot because Stack Overflow was actually escaping the characters correctly!

My question is, how do I get the original text (with all characters) to display when sending the quote to Twitter?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got around it with this:

```
var elem = document.createElement('textarea');
            elem.innerHTML = tweetText;
            tweetText = elem.value;
```

Basically, the text was sent as HTML encoded from the API so I had to decode it prior to building the URL.